# How to efficiently flatten a map?

Tags: go, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, pass-by-reference, flatten

My app needs to take a large array of nested instances of `map[string]interface{}` and turn them into flattened maps.

For example:

```
{
                "foo": {
                    "jim":"bean"
                },
                "fee": "bar",
                "n1": {
                    "alist": [
                        "a",
                        "b",
                        "c",
                        {
                            "d": "other",
                            "e": "another"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "number": 1.4567,
                "bool":   true
}
```

After:

```
json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &out)
result = Flatten(m.(map[string]interface{}))
```

Becomes:

```
{
                "foo.jim":      "bean",
                "fee":          "bar",
                "n1.alist.0":   "a",
                "n1.alist.1":   "b",
                "n1.alist.2":   "c",
                "n1.alist.3.d": "other",
                "n1.alist.3.e": "another",
                "number":       1.4567,
                "bool":         true,
}
```

Currently I am using the below code:

```
func Flatten(m map[string]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    o := map[string]interface{}{}
    for k, v := range m {
        switch child := v.(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:
            nm := Flatten(child)
            for nk, nv := range nm {
                o[k+"."+nk] = nv
            }
        case []interface{}:
            for i := 0; i < len(child); i++ {
                o[k+"."+strconv.Itoa(i)] = child[i]
            }
        default:
            o[k] = v
        }
    }
    return o
}
```

This code is very memory inefficient, when flatting ~800 maps, ~8 GiB memory is used.
I have tried passing pointers instead of copies, but that does not change the memory usage. Do I have to do some type of manual memory management? Go should garbage collect any unused memory, but it might be that I am not releasing it somehow.

Comment: Have you tried only having one result map and passing that to each invocation of `Flatten` along with the path to that point (i.e., the concatenated keys)? That way you don't have to create a new map with each invocation and copy the entries after `Flatten` returns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Andy Schweig suggested in the comments passing in a map which is updated as you iterate through the data should significantly reduce memory usage (note: have not tested). Something like:

```golang
func Flatten2(prefix string, src map[string]interface{}, dest map[string]interface{}) {
    if len(prefix) > 0 {
        prefix += "."
    }
    for k, v := range src {
        switch child := v.(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:
            Flatten2(prefix+k, child, dest)
        case []interface{}:
            for i := 0; i < len(child); i++ {
                dest[prefix+k+"."+strconv.Itoa(i)] = child[i]
            }
        default:
            dest[prefix+k] = v
        }
    }
}
```

Try this in [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SLJoDs4MK5x).

> Do I have to do some type of manual memory management?

The Go runtime is designed to handle memory management for you (see the FAQ article on [garbage collection](https://golang.org/doc/faq#garbage_collection)). While the garbage collector is very good it can only free memory that is not in use and your original routine created a lot of maps as it went which could not be freed until that level of the map had been processed.

There are a few flags you can set through [environmental variables](https://godoc.org/runtime#hdr-Environment_Variables) or using the [debug package](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/) but its rare that these are needed (and they can have unintended consequences).

> Any suggestions on where to further optimize this function?

Its difficult to comment without access to your dataset along with an understanding of your requirements and info on how you are measuring memory usage (this can be more complicated than it appears). [Profiling](https://blog.golang.org/pprof) your application may give you some pointers on areas for improvement. One possible improvement would be to use a pre-allocated slice rather than a map for `dest` (but I don't know what you are doing with the result so this may not be appropriate).

Comment: This strategy significantly decreased the memory used, it is very helpful. It now uses ~2 GiB for the same dataset. Any suggestions on where to further optimize this function?

Comment: I have added a few comments; however the best approach will depend upon your dataset (and the format you need the result in).

Comment: A slice for dest is good option, but will require a bit of refactoring in other places.

Comment: I would test before making major changes (the difference may not be significant enough to be worthwhile).

Comment: The dataset is file attributes from [FSCrawler](https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), each map can have varied sizes and depths. The required output format is a bit loose, but needs to remain easy to iterate over.

Comment: On the profiling: I am able to profile my code for memory issues, but am still very new to it and do not know how to use the tools well. The information I could find was confusing and different sources suggested very different methods. That is probably another question though.

Comment: Just run the playground code, it seems that there is still a map (i.e. unflattened) in the result. It's the `d` and `e` fields from the `alist`; so this doesn't completely flatten all the fields?

Comment: @dragonfly02 my intent was to reproduce the results of the original code which does not flatten maps within an array. If that is what you want you would need to change the handling in `case []interface{}:` ([something like this](https://go.dev/play/p/Q6io_T48z2s)).

Answer (score 2):

I've just written some code to do just that, enjoy!

```golang
import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type pair struct {
    key    []string
    isRoot bool
    value  interface{}
}

// FlattenMap flattens a given Map.
func FlattenMap(input map[string]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    var returnValue = make(map[string]interface{})

    var stack = list.New()
    stack.PushBack(pair{key: []string{}, isRoot: true, value: input})

    for {
        element := stack.Back()
        if element == nil {
            break
        }
        stack.Remove(element)

        thePair, ok := element.Value.(pair)
        if !ok {
            panic("can't cast element to pair")
        }

        switch v := thePair.value.(type) {
        // Handle generic maps.
        case map[string]interface{}:
            for key, val := range v {
                if thePair.isRoot {
                    stack.PushBack(pair{key: []string{key}, value: val})
                } else {
                    newKeys := append(thePair.key, key)
                    stack.PushBack(pair{key: newKeys, value: val})
                }
            }
        // Handle arrays.
        case []interface{}:
            lastKey := thePair.key[len(thePair.key)-1]
            for index, val := range v {
                newKeys := make([]string, len(thePair.key))
                itemsCopied := copy(newKeys, thePair.key)
                newKeys[itemsCopied-1] = fmt.Sprintf("%s[%d]", lastKey, index)
                stack.PushBack(pair{key: newKeys, value: val})
            }
        // Handle simple values.
        default:
            returnValue[strings.Join(thePair.key, ".")] = v
        }
    }

    return returnValue
}
```

Comment: why do you return a pointer to the map instead of the map? I thought passing around the map would already pass by reference.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks for pointing out. I've updated the code.

Comment: no worries, just wondering if that was a better way of passing stuff around :)

Comment: is `container/list` a open source package?

Comment: @dragonfly02 [`container/list`](https://pkg.go.dev/container/list) is part of the standard library.